# How to convert many .csv files into 1 .xlsx file with multiple tabs

Tags: conversion, tabs, csv, xlsx

I have multiple .csv files that need to be in a single .xlsx file, each on it's own tab. I know how to do it manually.  is there an automated way do do this? I'm going to need to do this on a monthly basis and there are too many .csv files to do this manually every month

Comment: You'll need a macro. If they are in the same directory, it's pretty simple. Try to figure it out and then come back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a macro to automate the import of CSVs. Take a look at Laszlo's answer in this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162477/importing-multiple-csv-to-multiple-worksheet-in-a-single-workbook), I think you can adapt its macro to your needs.